# how to set width when text has so long?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I make this for use slider , but when text is long or resize page text in 2 line but I need just one line and show all text. I need it to work in IE 9 and firefox.

you can see project in [codepen](https://codepen.io/soodeh/pen/VOWGRo)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.train {
  /*width: 100px;*/
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32%;
  right: -100%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  animation: train 20s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: train 8s linear infinite;
  text-align: right;
}

#one {
  background: yellow;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#two {
  background: blue;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#three {
  background: green;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#four {
  background: red;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes train {
  to {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes train {
  to {
    right: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="train" id="one">
      test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 finish
    </li>
    <li class="train" id="two">
      test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 v test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 v test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 v test 2 test2 test 2 test2 test 2 test2 finish
    </li>
    <li class="train" id="three">
      test 3 test3 finish
    </li>
    <li class="train" id="four">
      test 4 test 4 test 4 finish
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want the text not to break to the new line. Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;` on each of your element with the class `.train`?

Answer (score 0):

If your text does not fit into the container, it will be moved to another line.
You can add

```
> white-space: nowrap;
```

Or add to element with .train class the following styles:

```
> display: block;
> overflow: hidden;
> text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

These styles will cut the text and add a dotted line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

but IE9 not support animation, you can use javascript for slider